# Node.js, Express, MongoDB - cluster worker crashes

Tags: node.js, express

My problem is one of the workers in the cluster crashes when I hit an express route.

4 workers:

```
API started on port 8000
API started on port 8000
API started on port 8000
API started on port 8000
```

Then I browse to `http://localhost:8000`

```
worker 1 has died :(
```

After the worker dies, the whole cluster becomes unresponsive. 
It works fine when I only use one cpu.

**server.js**

```
var cluster = require('cluster');


if(cluster.isMaster){

    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker:' + worker.id + " is dead");
        cluster.fork();
    });

} else {
    var init = require('./config/init')();
    var config = require('./config/config');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var chalk = require('chalk');

    var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
            console.log(chalk.red(err));
        }
    });

    var app = require('./config/express')(db);

    app.listen(config.port);

    require('./config/passport')();

    console.log('API started on port ' + config.port);   
}
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to log the exit/signal code when a worker dies. See [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_exit).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to to try [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/), which supports multitasking (threads/instances under single process). From that reason clustering is not needed any more. Who knows, maybe this would work better for you.

So let's say, that you take just a worker code (I just paste it here without any change):

```
var init = require('./config/init')();
var config = require('./config/config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var chalk = require('chalk');

var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
    console.log(chalk.red(err));
  }
});

var app = require('./config/express')(db); 
app.listen(config.port);
require('./config/passport')();
console.log('API started on port ' + config.port);
```

and then you run it with [mt-keep](http://jxcore.com/docs/jxcore-command-mt.html) parameter (meaning: "multithread-keepalive"):

```
$ jxcore mt-keep:4 worker.js
```

The number `4` states for `4 cores` - please change it to fit your platform.

**Please note that I didn't test it.** I'm just showing an alternative to the multi-process clusters. Also, depending on the implementation, JXcore may be even more efficient.

There is an one-year old article, which highlights performance differences between JXcore and Node.JS: [JXcore vs Vert.x vs Node.JS Cluster](http://jxcore.com/nodejx-vs-vert-x-vs-node-js-cluster/).